# SOAP KeyInfo failed to recognise by IIS Server and client is java

Tags: java, .net, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I am getting following error while consuming .Net Web Service from java Spring 
Web Service uses Certificate based authentication.
I tried java(Server) to java(Client)  working locally using HTTPS and without https 
Even .Net Side  Server and client working.

```
    org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Referenced security token could not be retrieved ---> 
WSE590: Failed to resolve the following Key Info 
    <KeyInfo Id="KI-A65A1CE3CB2EB7AE6114286591136763" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <ds:X509Data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=VXX,OU=NXX,O=iXXX,L=Cty,ST=MH,C=IN</ds:X509IssuerName>
                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>1711043036</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </KeyInfo>.
```

I am using org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor

 to intercept request and response.
I don't understand whats happening at .Net side as its developed by other team.

  But .Net Team told request is not reached to applcation, IIS server itself not able to process this.

Please find .Net client calling code snippet.

```
// TODO: Replace with a valid path to your certificate
   string certPath = @"C:\mypath\certClient1.cer";
   Secured.TSRService objsecserv = new Secured.TSRService();

   objsecserv.Url = @"https://xyz/service.asmx";
   //objsecserv.Url = @"http://xyz:97/service.asmx";

   objsecserv.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certPath));
    objsecserv.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
    string strresult1 = objsecserv.GetCertDetails();

    rtxtresult.Text = strresult1;
```

And Here is my java side code snippet

```
<bean id="countryWsClSecInterId" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="securementActions" value="Timestamp Signature" />  <!-- Encrypt -->
    <!--    Key alias for signature -->
    <property name="securementUsername" value="client" />
    <property name="securementPassword" value="mypasswd" />
    <property name="securementSignatureCrypto" ref="countryCrypto"/>
    <property name="securementEncryptionCrypto" ref="countryCrypto"/>
    <!-- Key alias for encryption -->
    <property name="securementEncryptionUser" value="server"/>  
    <!-- Validation config -->
    <property name="validationActions" value="Signature" />
    <property name="validationSignatureCrypto" ref="countryCrypto"/>
</bean>
```

Please guide me , I searched a lot and made changes according but nothing worked.